# User must like page before viewing

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-like

I have struggled with this for quite some time now but figured I would revisit the issue. My goal is to do the same type of thing This facebook page is doing https://www.facebook.com/JimBeam?sk=app_140011936063255

They have made it so that the user must click the like button before reviewing the content.

My normal procedure is to build a welcome.HTML page, create a new app on fb, then assign page to the correct business.

My question is if I designed a new html page, let's call it pre-like.HTML, where would I drop in the code so that this page design displays prior to users being able to see the welcome page?

I guess once the like button is clicked it would redirect users to the welcome page? I would greatly appreciate any advice or good tutorials you could send my way on doing this.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Hopefully these sorts of shenanigans will eventually kill Facebook.

Comment: -1. Requiring likes to see the page's content is the most annoying thing on the entire Facebook. I leave those pages immediately.

Let me review your content first, and let me decide whether I like it or not, please.

It's even more annoying when websites bugging you to like them on Facebook even if you don't have Facebook!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because anybody who answers this question is a dick.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1mb7axz - SO, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I found this information for you.  [FACEBOOK SECRET HIDE CONTENT ON FAN PAGE UNTIL SOMEONE LIKES IT](http://mrinternettips.com/facebook-secret-hide-content-on-fan-page-until-someone-likes-it/)

> you need to add this in the part of your PHP file you want to display a different message for non fans and fans.

```
 <?php

 $request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];</p>
 <p>list($encoded_sig, $load) = explode('.', $request, 2);</p>
 <p>$fbData = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($load, '-_', '+/')), true);</p>
 <p>if (!empty($fbData["page"]["liked"]))</p>
 <p>{ ?></p>
 <p>You are a fan - insert html here</p>
 <p><?php } else { ?></p>
 <p>You are not a fan - insert html here</p>
 <p>

 <?php } ?>
```

Hope that helps!  I strongly recommend you hit the link I sourced the info from and go follow his directions.  The article is dated from October, so I think this might the most recent info out there on the web.

Answer (score 1):

When the user opens your app, facebook does a post request (via a hidden form) to your application's canvas url. It contains a `signed_request` parameter, that you can verify with your app secret, then decode. It contains some info about the user even before he/she adds your app, and it also has whether he/she liked the page the app is in.

See the [documentation of the signed request parameter](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) for more detailed information and also a php example of verifying/decoding it.

It's a bit hidden, but you'll need to test `$decoded_data->page->liked`, it's possibly enough to be included in your landing page.

Answer (score 0):

I would check on the server when you get the request for the welcome page. That way you know you are getting the correct information. If they have't liked the page, send them back to the landing page, otherwise allow them to see the welcome page.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Abby but I'm not sure I understand your comment. Basically I am currently just I framing my simple welcom.HTML pages into fb. I set up those app's through the  developers portal then assign it to the fan page of my choice. I'm again just trying to figure out the process of how to go about setting up a fb with a must like option fist in order to see anything else on the fan page. Again this site gives you an idea of exactly what I am trying to do. https://www.facebook.com/JimBeam?sk=app_140011936063255

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure my suggestion still stands. As mentioned in Maerlyn's reponse, you can get the signed_request data to check on your server if the page has been liked, and send them to the landing page if they haven't, and main page if they have